# Make a panel under a button that overlays another element

Tags: css, reactjs, css-position, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I have an editor and several buttons above it on the right. I would like to have a panel just under `Button2` that overlays the editor. Then, clicking on `Button2` will expand and collapse the panel (which will be easy to implement).

I have written the following code: https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-mclaren-3mrtyj?file=/src/App.js. At the moment, the panel is NOT under `Button2` and does NOT overlay the editor.

Does anyone know how to amend the CSS?

```
import React from "react";
import { Stack } from "@fluentui/react";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Stack horizontal horizontalAlign="space-between">
          <div>Title</div>
          <div>Button1 Button2 Button3</div>
        </Stack>
        <div
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "yellow",
            width: "350px",
            height: "50px"
          }}
        >
          A floating panel which is supposed to be always under "Button2" and
          overlays the editor.
        </div>
        <div
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "gray",
            width: "100%",
            height: "300px"
          }}
        >
          An editor
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: in your snippet, the buttons don't have a parent (`<button>`), are you gonna implement that later? is it fine if the panel section is moved to be inside the buttons? when you said that it should be under button2, what do you mean by that? is it directly below the button2? (the way I see it, it's already under button2, maybe not in x axis though, but how exactly do you want the position to be?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does this look?

https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-platform-q3v4kc?file=/src/App.js

I moved the floating pane into the button, made the button position relative, and made the floating pane position absolute.

*Note:* notice there's no `top` property on the floating pane. One neat thing about position absolute is if you don't set top, left, bottom, right those positions will be where that box would be if it wasn't position absolute.

Comment: This is close to what I expected; the panel is not necessarily big. I added some code to enable `Button2`: https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-voice-ex6gxc?file=/src/App.js

Comment: What do you mean by "the panel is not necessarily big"? Are you saying it's too big?

Comment: I was misleading by saying "overlay", other answers made the panel cover the editor, but it's not what I meant, I would expect a small panel like yours.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `position:absolute` on floating pane and add it in the editor div which will have `position:relative`.You can see the result it works fine
On clicking button 2 the floating panel hides/shows alternatively

#### This will work.

```js
var btn=document.querySelector('.drop_btn');
    btn.onclick=function()
    {
      document.querySelector('.dropdown').classList.toggle('block');
    }
```

```css
*
        {
            font-family: 'arial';
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        .menu_pane
        {
            display: flex;
            background: #151515;
            color: white;
            padding:5px 10px;
            align-items: center;
            border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
        }

        .menu_pane h3
        {
            font-weight: normal;
            font-size: 18px;
            flex-grow: 1;
        }

        .menu_pane .btn button
        {
            position: relative;
            background: #0971F1;
            color: white;
            border-radius: 5px;
            border:none;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 8px 20px;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }

        .dropdown
        {
            display: none;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            color: white !important;
            position: absolute;
            background: #242424;
            border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
        }

        .menu_pane .btn .dropdown p
        {
            font-size: 14px;
        }
        .editor_pane
        {
            position: relative;
          background:#151515;
          color: white;
          min-height: 50vh;
          border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
          padding: 10px;
          color: #512DA8;
        }
        
        .block
        {
            display: block;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="menu_pane">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        
        <div class="btn">
        <button>Button-1</button>
        </div>

        <div class="btn">
        <button class="drop_btn">Button-2</button>

        </div>

        <div class="btn">
        <button>Button-3</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="editor_pane">
        <p>An editor</p>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <p>A floating panel which is supposed to be always under "Button2" and overlays the editor.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just wanna point out OPs example is using React so that Javascript snippet in this answer is unrelated to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

I noticed that the overlay needed to cover the "editor" area only and have the example updated with hopefully the right placement of it.

Updated live example: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/panel-overlay-2-idb3ys?file=/src/App.js)

```
import React from "react";
import { Stack } from "@fluentui/react";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = { showOverlay: true };
  handleToggle = () =>
    this.setState((prev) => ({ showOverlay: !prev.showOverlay }));

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Stack
          horizontal
          horizontalAlign="space-between"
          style={{ padding: "12px" }}
        >
          <div>Title</div>
          <Stack horizontal>
            <button>Button1</button>
            <button onClick={this.handleToggle}>
              {`Button2 (${this.state.showOverlay ? "Hide" : "Show"} Overlay)`}
            </button>
            <button>Button3</button>
          </Stack>
        </Stack>
        <div
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "gray",
            width: "100%",
            height: "300px",
            position: "relative"
          }}
        >
          An editor
          <div
            style={{
              position: "absolute",
              inset: "0",
              backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.70)",
              display: this.state.showOverlay ? "flex" : "none",
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center",
              color: "#fff"
            }}
          >
            A floating panel which is supposed to be always under "Button2" and
            overlays the editor.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Keeping the original example (it had overlay on the whole component except for "Button 2") just in case if it might be useful.

**Original**

Not sure if I fully understand the desired result, but here is the component implemented with a toggle overlay controlled by `Button2`.

The overlay is currently set on top of and blocking all child elements except for `Button2`, so that it works as a "start editing" button, but it can be further adjusted to specify which element it covers to better suit the use case.

Quick demo of the example: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/panel-overlay-1-pq2eu3?file=/src/App.js)

```
import React from "react";
import { Stack } from "@fluentui/react";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = { showOverlay: true };
  handleToggle = () =>
    this.setState((prev) => ({ showOverlay: !prev.showOverlay }));

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ position: "relative", zIndex: "1" }}>
        <Stack
          horizontal
          horizontalAlign="space-between"
          style={{ padding: "12px" }}
        >
          <div>Title</div>
          <Stack horizontal>
            <button>Button1</button>
            <button style={{ zIndex: "75" }} onClick={this.handleToggle}>
              {`Button2 (${this.state.showOverlay ? "Hide" : "Show"} Overlay)`}
            </button>
            <button>Button3</button>
          </Stack>
        </Stack>
        <div
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            inset: "0",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.70)",
            zIndex: "50",
            display: this.state.showOverlay ? "flex" : "none",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
            color: "#fff",
          }}
        >
          A floating panel which is supposed to be always under "Button2" and
          overlays the editor.
        </div>
        <div
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "gray",
            width: "100%",
            height: "300px",
          }}
        >
          An editor
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry that I think I was misleading by saying "overlay", the panel does not need to cover the area of the editor.